# .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby: No such file or directory on Cygwin

Tags: ruby, windows, cygwin, zsh, rbenv

To install rbenv, I installed Cygwin and some required packages (gcc, openssl, libssl, libxml, etc). Then, cloned repositories and appended to.zshrc.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugin
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Restarted cygwin and ran this command.

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p353
```

However I got this error.

```
$ rbenv install 2.0.0-p353
Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p353.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/78282433fb697dd3613613ff55d734c1
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p353...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20140211033802.7944
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20140211033802.7944.log

Last 10 log lines:
installing default gems:      /cygdrive/c/Users/MY_NAME/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0 (build_info, cache, doc, gems, specifications)
                              bigdecimal 1.2.0
                              io-console 0.4.2
                              json 1.7.7
                              minitest 4.3.2
                              psych 2.0.0
                              rake 0.9.6
                              rdoc 4.0.0
                              test-unit 2.0.0.0
/cygdrive/c/Users/MY_NAME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/ruby-build: line 759: /cygdrive/c/Users/MY_NAME/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

/tmp/ruby-build.20140211033802.7944 is here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a9e099a4335ae59a9714

I found a function related to openssl around line 759 of ruby-build, but I may have installed 
it.
Any ideas on why versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby doesn't exist?

Comment: It may be due to rbenv not being supported on Windows. That is what this [link](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/15/using-rbenv-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-ruby/) says anyway. Ctrl-f windows to find the specific section about not supporting windows.